# Display the knitr code chunk source in document

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm trying to output the source of a knitr chunk onto a beamer slide.

For example, I would like the following code chunk to be displayed as is in the .Rnw:

```
<<code-chunk, echo=TRUE, tidy=TRUE>>=
@
```

I've attempted to recreate this behavior using:

```
<<out-first-code-chunk, echo=FALSE, comment=NA>>=
cat(paste("<<example-code-chunk, echo=TRUE, tidy=TRUE>>=","@",sep="\n"))
@
```

This code is legitimate since the cat command in R's console gives:

```
> cat('<<example-code-chunk, echo=TRUE, tidy=TRUE>>=','@',sep='\n')
<<code-chunk, echo=TRUE, tidy=TRUE>>=
@
```

However, the resulting latex:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Code Chunk}
To incorporate R code into your knitr documents
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{verbatim}
<<example-code-chunk, echo=TRUE, tidy=TRUE>>=
@
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}
```

Throws errors:

```
<<example-code-chunk, echo=TRUE, tidy=TRUE>>= @ \end {verbatim} \end
\ETC. ! Paragraph ended before \@xverbatim was complete. <to be read
again> \par l.198 \end{frame} I suspect you've forgotten a `}',
causing me to apply this control sequence to too much text. How can we
recover? My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best. !
LaTeX Error: \begin{verbatim} on input line 198 ended by
\end{beamer@framepau ses}. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for
explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.198 \end{frame}
Your command was ignored. Type I <command> <return> to replace it with
another command, or <return> to continue without it. ! LaTeX Error:
\begin{kframe} on input line 198 ended by \end{beamer@frameslide }.
```

Why is the latex environment thinking that verbatim was not closed? Is there a more appropriate way to display a code-chunk in its entirety?

Comment: You probably need `\begin{frame}[fragile]`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140719/verbatim-in-beamer-showing-error-file-ended-while-scanning-use-of-xverbatim

Comment: Check this package out [knitLiteral](https://github.com/Thell/knitLiteral/). It allows code chunks to be printed verbatim without using any `cat` tricks.

Comment: Thank you both very much! Very helpful. I did indeed need [fragile]. knitLiteral is also very handy for more complex code chunks.

Comment: @Coatless, you're welcome to post a version of my comment as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it...

1 line in the setup chunk, and 1 extra param in the chunk desired for output...

Console:

```
`install.packages(devtools)`  
`devtools::install_github("thell/knitliteral")`
```

For `.Rnw`:

```
<<"knitr-setup", include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
knitLiteral::kast_on()
@

<<"my_chunk", eval=FALSE, opts.label="literal-literal">>=
# Something that will not be output in the doc.
@
```

Output:

```
<<"my_chunk", eval=FALSE>>=
@
```

---

For `.Rmd`:

`````
````{r knitr_setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
knitLiteral::kast_on()
````

````{r my_chunk, opts.label="literal-literal"}
# Something that will not be output in the doc.
````
`````

Output:

`````
````{r my_chunk}
````
`````

<sup><sub>** The use of 4 backticks keeps syntax highlighting as valid `R` (where used).</sub></sup>

From this chunk and what you can see in the source of the example [Literal Markdown](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Thell/knitLiteral/master/inst/examples/Literal-markdown.Rmd) doc and the [rendered doc](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/14795_f3e5011d9e65499fb66616265b308a2d.html) that there is no need to have a complex chunk.

The [sweave example file](https://github.com/Thell/knitLiteral/blob/master/inst/examples/Literal-sweave.Rnw) is also available showing the same examples.